# Add list open invoice in odoo qweb invoice report?

Tags: odoo, qweb

I would like to add a list open invoice in the bottom of account.report_invoice_document in odoo 11, i'll tried to execute other code in qweb report but cannot work. how can i do?

Please help me,
tnx.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all please what report you are talking about. and where you need to add them

Comment: sorry, my english is not good,
i'd like to customize customer invoice report in odoo 11, the report is account.report_invoice_document.

tnx